# Extracting words between word/space patterns

Tags: r, regex, string, text-mining

I have some data where I have names "sandwiched" between two spaces and the phrase "is a (number from 1-99) y.o". For example:

```
a <- "SomeOtherText  John Smith is a 60 y.o. MoreText"
b <- "YetMoreText  Will Smth Jr. is a 30 y.o. MoreTextToo"
c <- "JustJunkText  Billy Smtih III is 5 y/o MoreTextThree"
```

I'd like to extract the names "John Smith", "Will Smth Jr." and "Billy Smtih III" (the misspellings are there on purpose). I tried using `str_extract` or `gsub`, based on answers to similar questions I found on SO, but with no luck.

Comment: What exactly did you try that didn't work?

Answer (score 1):

You can chain multiple calls to stringr::str_remove.
First regex: remove pattern that start with (`^`) any letters (`[:alpha:]`) followed by one or more whitespaces (`\\s+`).
Seconde regex: remove pattern that ends with (`$`) a whitespace(`\\s`) followed by the sequence `is`, followed by any number of non-newline characters (`.`)

```
str_remove(a, '^[:alpha:]*\\s+') %>% str_remove("\\sis.*$")

[1] "John Smith"

str_remove(b, '^[:alpha:]*\\s+') %>% str_remove("\\sis.*$")

[1] "Will Smth Jr."

str_remove(c, '^[:alpha:]*\\s+') %>% str_remove("\\sis.*$")

[1] "Billy Smtih III"
```

You can also do it in a single call by using `stringr::str_remove_all` and joining the two patterns separated by an OR (`|`) symbol:

```
str_remove_all(a, '^[:alpha:]*\\s+|\\sis.*$')
str_remove_all(b, '^[:alpha:]*\\s+|\\sis.*$')
str_remove_all(c, '^[:alpha:]*\\s+|\\sis.*$')
```

Comment: I wanted to keep the "is a [1-99] y.o." part because the text after that could also have a two space pattern followed by "is".

Comment: The `.*` means a greedy matching, so you will usually remove the whole rest of the characters after the first appearence of `is`.
If you have a condition other than that specified in the question you should update the question

Answer (score 0):

You can use `sub` in base R as -

```
extract_name <- function(x) sub('.*\\s{2,}(.*)\\sis.*\\d+ y[./]o.*', '\\1', x)

extract_name(c(a, b, c))
#[1] "John Smith"      "Will Smth Jr."   "Billy Smtih III"
```

`\\s{2,}`  is 2 or more whitespace

`(.*)` capture group to capture everything until

`is` followed by a number and `y.o` and `y/o` is encountered.